# Wordpress PHP - How to show header on every page?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

If anyone can help it would be much appreciated. I'm working on a Wordpress site and I have a header image on the homepage. It's only showing up on the homepage but I need it to show on every page. I found this code in the header.php file which I believe needs to be changed, but I'm not very familiar with php.

This is the code for the header image in the header.php file:

```
<?php if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) { ?>
  <?php if ( get_header_image() != '' && $papercuts_options_db['papercuts_display_header_image'] != 'Everywhere except Homepage' ) { ?>
    <div class="header-image-wrapper"><div class="header-image"><img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" /></div></div>
  <?php 
    }  
  } else { ?>
  <?php if ( get_header_image() != '' && $papercuts_options_db['papercuts_display_header_image'] != 'Only on Homepage' ) { ?>
      <div class="header-image-wrapper"><div class="header-image"><img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" /></div></div>
  <?php } 
  } ?>
```

Comment: find the main template php used for all pages and call the header.php at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the code with this:

```
<?php 
if ( get_header_image() != '' ) { 
?>
    <div class="header-image-wrapper"><div class="header-image"><img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" /></div></div>
<?php 
}
?>
```

And ideally keep the original code but commented out - use:

```
<?php 
/*
if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) { ?>
  <?php if ( get_header_image() != '' && $papercuts_options_db['papercuts_display_header_image'] != 'Everywhere except Homepage' ) { ?>
    <div class="header-image-wrapper"><div class="header-image"><img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" /></div></div>
  <?php 
    }  
  } else { ?>
  <?php if ( get_header_image() != '' && $papercuts_options_db['papercuts_display_header_image'] != 'Only on Homepage' ) { ?>
      <div class="header-image-wrapper"><div class="header-image"><img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" /></div></div>
      <?php } 

  } 
*/ ?>
```

For reference

Comment: This worked, thanks! Do you know how I could make the header NOT show up on specific pages by chance? It turns out I need it to show on some pages and not on others.

Comment: You can get the page info and display accordingly - get_the_title(); will get you the title for example so you could add:

$postID = get_the_ID();
if ( get_header_image() != ''  && $postID != 5) {

If the page id of the page you don't want to show it on is 5, you can just repeat the && $postID != bit if you want to add others

Answer (score -3):

```
 <?php if ( get_header_image() !='') { ?>
    <div class="header-image-wrapper"><div class="header-image"><img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" /></div></div>
  <?php 
     } ?>
```

Replace  the code  with above. I think  it will work.